# Which software or settings to manage hot swap between ethernet and wifi? [Roaming]

Tags: networking, ethernet, wireless-roaming

My problem: on Windows 10, when I switch between Wifi and Ethernet and back, my computer changes it's IP address (IPv4).

Several software doesn't tolerate it and fail.

I wish to have some roaming capability to be connected on both Wifi and Ethernet and that some layer manages this switch without functionality drop.

Does that exist? Is there already something included in Windows 10 Pro that can do that?

Comment: Setup your DHCP in a way that your machine gets a consistent address? What software specifically fails? You will have a tiny service interruption during a switchover.

Comment: You will only change IP address if your Wireless and Wired are on different subnets.  Either make your connections on the same subnets and Windows 10 will do this automatically. Or, if in different environments, you cannot avoid changing IP addresses

Comment: What software: Windows Remote Desktop Connection, TN5250 telnet terminals, sometimes Skype, Microsoft Teams.
Especially from Wifi to Ethernet in my case.

Comment: You should not try to swap hardware connections with active connections in process, but on the same subnet, you can simply plug in Ethernet and it will connect.